# File output with random numbers

Tags: java

```
    /**
    This class simulates rolling a pair of dice 10,000 times and
    counts the number of times doubles of are rolled for each different
    pair of doubles.
    */

    import java.util.Random;        //to use the random number generator 
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import java.io.*;

    import org.omg.PortableServer.ImplicitActivationPolicyOperations;



     public class DiceSimulation
     {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
     {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int NUMBER = 10000;   //the number of times to roll the dice

        //a random number generator used in simulating rolling a dice
        Random generator = new Random();

        int die1Value;          // number of spots on the first die
        int die2Value;          // number of spots on the second die
        int count = 0;          // number of times the dice were rolled
        int snakeEyes = 0;      // number of times snake eyes is rolled
        int twos = 0;           // number of times double two is rolled
        int threes = 0;         // number of times double three is rolled
        int fours = 0;          // number of times double four is rolled
        int fives = 0;          // number of times double five is rolled
        int sixes = 0;          // number of times double six is rolled
        String filename;        //name of file to write/read
        int accumulator = 0;
        double mean = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        String userInput;
        // add code for TASK #3 
        System.out.println("Please enter a specific path to a file");

        filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);




        //loop while count is less than NUMBER of times
        //adjust code in while loop as instructed in TASK #3



        while(count < NUMBER)
        {
            //roll the dice
            die1Value = generator.nextInt(6)+1;
            die2Value = generator.nextInt(6)+1;
            //Check to see if you have doubles
            //Enter code for Task 1 if statements here
            if (die1Value == die2Value);
                if (die1Value == 1){
                    snakeEyes++;
                    outputFile.println ("Snake eyes occurred a total of " +                snakeEyes + " times");}
                else if(die1Value == 2){
                    twos++;}
                else if(die1Value == 3){
                    threes++;}
                else if(die1Value == 4){
                    fours++;}
                else if(die1Value == 5){
                    fives++;}
                else if(die1Value == 6){
                    sixes++;}
        count++;





        }   //while(count < NUMBER) ending braces;

    //add code that closes the output file for TASK #3 here/////////////////
                outputFile.close();

        System.out.println ("Output for while loop");
        System.out.println ("You rolled snake eyes " + snakeEyes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double twos " + twos +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double threes " + threes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fours " + fours +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fives " + fives +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double sixes " + sixes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");


        //Enter code for TASK #2 here for do while loop

        do{
        System.out.println("Count: " + count);
        } while (count < NUMBER);
        //roll the dice
        die1Value = generator.nextInt(6)+1;
        die2Value = generator.nextInt(6)+1;
        //Check to see if you have doubles
        //Enter code for Task 1 if statements here


        System.out.println ("\nOutput for do while loop\n");
        System.out.println ("You rolled snake eyes " + snakeEyes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double twos " + twos +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double threes " + threes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fours " + fours +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fives " + fives +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double sixes " + sixes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
       // Enter code for TASK #2 here for for loop
       for(count = 1; count <= NUMBER; count++)
        break;
        System.out.println ("Output for, for loop\n");
        System.out.println ("You rolled snake eyes " + snakeEyes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double twos " + twos +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double threes " + threes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fours " + fours +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double fives " + fives +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");
        System.out.println ("You rolled double sixes " + sixes +
            " out of " + count + " rolls.");

    // add code for TASK #4 here



    }
}
```

The point in which I am stuck is in the first `while` statement, where I am trying to output the results of the different rolls into a separate `.txt`.

The outputting works fine, but when it goes through it outputs every single instance of the roll, so when all instances are outputted there are 10,000 lines for all of the rolls of the dice.

**How can I make it output only the total number of each type of roll?**

Comment: Are you trying to output the number of rolls for doubles or for all combinations of 2 dice?

Comment: Just the doubles

Answer (score 0):

By writing different information to that file?!

Who says that you have to print to the output file within that loop?

You already collect your counter statistics in that loop (to print them AFTER the loop). Just do the same regarding the output file.

Beyond that: read about arrays. When you start using variable names such as a1, a2 and so on... Such code always becomes much simpler by using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you would want to include this code just before the `outputFile.close();`

```
//add code that closes the output file for TASK #3 here/////////////////
outputFile.println ("Snake eyes occurred a total of " + snakeEyes + " times");
outputFile.println ("Twos occurred a total of " + twos + " times");
outputFile.println ("Threes occurred a total of " + threes + " times");
outputFile.println ("Fours occurred a total of " + fours + " times");
outputFile.println ("Fives occurred a total of " + fives + " times");
outputFile.println ("Sixes occurred a total of " + sixes + " times");
outputFile.close();
```

I would also recommend going over your code and reducing duplicate code by using methods and calling them when necessary.

Comment: Thank you. Id tried this earlier but did not have the close connected with the rest of the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to output for each double roll, just move the code that prints to the file out of your while loop and make it print the final result of your snake eyes, twos, threes, etc.